# remove or add items to dropdown based on values of other dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have three Dropdown lists with around 25 values. My goal is to remove an item from the other Dropdowns once it has been selected.

For example:
`ItemA` is selected in `Dropdown1`. `ItemA` then needs to be removed from `Dropdown2` and `Dropdown3`. If `ItemB` is selected in `Dropdown2` then it needs to be removed from `Dropdown1` and `Dropdown3`.

However, the problem that I run into is when a user changes the value of `Dropdown1` I then need to add that value to `Dropdown2` and `Dropdown3` again.

My initial thought was to have a master list of all the values that is populated when the page loads, and then use that as a reference point. Another option that I had considered was to disable and enable `Dropdown2` and `Dropdown3` based on if the previous dropdowns value was empty.

Here is some code that I have, but it doens't work very well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var q1 = document.getElementById('Dropdown1');
    var q2 = document.getElementById('Dropdown2');
    var q3 = document.getElementById('Dropdown3');
    var allQuestions = q1.options;

    function updateQuestions() {
        if (q1.value == '') {
            resetQuestions();
        } else {
            q2.disabled = false;
            q2.remove(q1.selectedIndex);
            q3.disabled = false;
            q3.remove(q1.selectedIndex);
        }

        if (q2.value == '') {
            q3.disabled = true;
            q3.value = '';
            q3.options = allQuestions;
        } else {
            q3.disabled = false;
            q3.remove(q1.selectedIndex);
            q3.remove(q2.selectedIndex);
        }
    }

    function resetQuestions() {
        q2.disabled = true;
        q3.disabled = true;
        q2.value = '';
        q3.value = '';
        q2.options = allQuestions;
        q3.options = allQuestions;
    }
</script>
```

It ends up removing the wrong object and by the time I get to `Dropdown3` it has around 8 values rather than the 23 it should have.

Edit: `UpdateQuestions()` is called when a dropdown is changed!

Comment: Whoops! Thought I had removed that! lol

Comment: You are removing items using index rather than using their values, this approach will work only if all of your drop downs have same items in same order. Share a fiddle it will be more helpful